# Need assistance regarding calculating distance using core location

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, core-location

Using iPhone and utilising core location I want to calculate a distance of a racing car on a racing track. The scenario is only one car will be on track at a time and track is also not straight. Its similar to TopGear program when they test cars one by one on track and you know that track is not straight.

I am fetching latitude, longitude, speed and sending it on web server to monitor things in real time.

The problems I am facing are:

1> When car runs on track it can run in zig zag manner. Tracks are broad and when can run on it car can be in left, middle or right lane. During car shift lanes its latitude and longitude are also recorded. Means if you draw a snake shape on paper from top to bottom and then draw a straight line from top to bottom, same goes in my scenario I want the actual distance?

I tried several things and tutorials but after running code on device and walking in a room back and forth distance keep increasing, but on track when those little movement can not be avoided, how do I get a correct distance?

2> For example if the track is of "U" shape and using `distanceFromLocation:` it gives "U" point to point distance but not the whole "U" track distance, like car starts from "U" left point to "U" right point. How to calculate whole "U" distance?

[I am following this tutorial.](http://www.perspecdev.com/blog/2012/02/22/using-corelocation-on-ios-to-track-a-users-distance-and-speed/)

Comment: If you're recording all the points then you can loop through them and add up the distances between each pair of points.

Comment: @Wain Thanks for replying, Please can you give a code snippet, how can I add distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're recording all the points then you can loop through them and add up the distances between each pair of points. To get the distance between all of the points (pseudo code):

```
double distance = 0;
CLLocationCoordinate2D p1 = ...;
CLLocationCoordinate2D p2 = ...;

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    distance += [self metresBetweenPlace1:p1 place2:p2];

    p1 = p2;
    p2 = ...;
}

- (double)metresBetweenPlace1:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)place1 andPlace2:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)place2
{
    MKMapPoint start = MKMapPointForCoordinate(place1);
    MKMapPoint finish = MKMapPointForCoordinate(place2);

    return MKMetersBetweenMapPoints(start, finish);
}
```

Comment: please view the zig zag issue I mentioned in my question, this solution will not give me accurate distance.

Comment: As stated by the other commenters you're limited by the accuracy of the device. This solution will give you the distance between each point and the total distance.

Comment: Assuming you're using `CLLocation` objects, you can simply do `[p2 distanceFromLocation:p1] `

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, You cannot do it very accurately only using internal GPS of iOS device. Because Internal GPS is updating only at 1Hz rate. For fast racing car, everything can happen within 1 seconds. Unless you use external GPS receiver which is high rate, you cannot achieve your goal. There are some GPS receivers for iOS in the marketing, you can google it. I am personally using Racelogic VBOX Sport which is 20Hz rate.

Then, I would use speed*time to calculate distance not using distanceFromLocation:. Because GPS can give you high accurate speed and UTC time, but cannot guarantee high accurate position (exact position).

If you don't worry about accuracy, you can do this way. When you get every single sample CLLocation, get speed and time(current timestamp minus previous timestamp) and multiply it and add this result to next sample result. e.g.

```
//Ignore if speed is less than 5 km/h
if (newLocation.speed < 1.39)
return;

//(average speed in m/s) * (time in seconds)
float result = (newLocation.speed + oldLocation.speed)/2 * [newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceDate:oldLocation.timestamp];
```

And sum up all results.

Comment: those cars are not that super fast thats why iphone will work in my case.

Comment: Then you can use speed*time to calculate your distance. It is more accurate than distanceFromLocation: function. I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for replying, I got bit confused in this " (current timestamp minus previous timestamp) and multiply it and add this result to next sample result. " please can you give a code snippet.

Comment: I undated answer with code. It only works when high accuracy is not needed ;]

Comment: beware if you break harsh and the vehcle stops, ios still gives 5km/h forever untill vehicle moves on. The reason is that in still stand you do not get a fix, like on an (unfiltered)  GPS device.

Comment: @AlexWien thanks for replying, please can you tell me how to filter this?

Comment: @AlexWien you are right. Actually In my code, I ignored if speed is less than 5 km/h :]

Comment: I have to disagree with speed being more accurate than location. I made an app that started logging location data when I clicked a button "start" and ended after moving 330 ft. I used the speed value to calculate distance just as you have above, but for every run I performed using `distanceFromLocation` (using the current location and saved startLocation) resulted in a more accurate reading.

Comment: That is so strange what you get. If you know how GPS is working, you wouldn't doubt my answer. GPS speed is using Doppler effect to calculate it and GPS timestamp is used for correcting your iPhone time since it is very accurate.

Comment: But I am not saying distanceFromLocation: is not accurate, the function is accurate. The problem is iPhone GPS position cannot give you exact position where you are. So that is why it is not accurate. The problem you get is, I guess, iPhone is updating 1Hz and you start just before you get newLocation. That means you have missed 1s for your testing. That is what my answer try to explain. DO NOT USE IT TO CALCULATE YOUR RACE!!!

Comment: Get speed before you pass start point. When you almost arrive at start point, press start button. And then when you almost arrive at finish point, press stop button. See results.

Comment: @brianLikeApple For my logging app, I come to a complete stop and wait for speed = 0. I take this as my `startLocation`. Then I click start and start driving forward until I hit 330 ft and take the time it took. I take the 2 `distanceTraveled` readings (calculated based on GPS location and also the speed distance method you have), and for the multiple runs I performed, the speed distance value was lagging behind the GPS location distance values. Using the GPS location readings it would record about 13 seconds taken, the speed distances about 16. For my testing I was driving in a straight line.

Comment: @brianLikeApple Also, I logged horizontalAccuracy for the entire test as well and each time I had 5.

Comment: @sbonkosky I think you didn't get my point. How do you know you hit exact 330ft? And how do you know your start point is 0ft? They are maybe 10m away from your position.

Comment: @brianLikeApple I have the distance measured off on the road. I take the last spot my speed was 0 as my start location, and once my speed is not 0 I begin my logging. This way every reading I get I get `distanceFromLocation` using `newLocation` and `startLocation`, and also calculate the distance using the change in velocity using `newLocation` and `previousLocation`. Each time, the `distanceFromStartLocation` using the GPS location is more accurate than the speed/distance calculation. My test conditions are a straight road, starting from speed=0, and never going over 25 mph.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29200/discussion-between-sbonkosky-and-brianlikeapple)

Comment: @sbonkosky you cannot simply sum up the distances between each Gps location, this is a bad algorithm, which will lead to a much higher distance, espcially for slow speeds ( walking, hiking,etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try inputting this code in your view controller, it worked for me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    locationManager =[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [userMap setCenterCoordinate: userMap.userLocation.coordinate animated: YES];
    [self performSelector:@selector(checkForLogin) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

    [self startLocationServices];
        // create LM
        self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];

        // set its delegate
        [self.locationManager setDelegate:self];

        // set configuration
        [self.locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
        [self.locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];

        // start location services
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    // create an oldLocation variable if one doesn't exist

    }


- (void)startLocationServices
{
    // create the Location Manager
    if (self.locationManager == nil) {
        self.locationManager = [CLLocationManager new];
    }

    // stop services
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    [self.locationManager setDelegate:nil];
    self.uilabel.text = @"0.0f";
}
// locationManager didUpdateToLocation FromLocation
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSLog(@"%@", newLocation);
      self.uilabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d %.f ", x, [newLocation speed] * 2.23694];


    }

 + (NSString *) speedToMPH: (float) value
{
 NSString *x = @"0.0 ";
 if (value>0) {
 float mile = 1609.344f;
 float mph = value / mile * 3600;
 x = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.f ", mph];
 }
 return x;
 }
```

and add this to you **.h file**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *uilabel;
@property(nonatomic) int x;
@property (nonatomic,retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;
+ (NSString *) speedToMPH: (float) value;
```